# Open URL in my WebView after loading it from YouTube's share menu

Tags: android, kotlin, webview

I have an Android WebView project and I have added it in the share menu to get the URL from YouTube.

[image: Screenshot from my phone after adding my app to share menu]

and I am using this code in manifest

```xml
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

I need the code to open the URL in the WebView after a click on my app icon from the share menu in YouTube.

For e.g.:

```
val intent = intent
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    val uri = intent.data

    if (uri == null){
        webframe.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")
    }else{
        webframe.loadUrl(uri.toString())
    }
```

Comment: webView.loadUrl(url);

Comment: This is the default
'webframe.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")'

i need load url after open share link

Comment: No i mean of course webView.loadUrl(url obtained from share intent); What else! You said: `i need the code to open the url in webview`.

Comment: thank you , yes i mean this

`if(intent.action.SEND){
  webview.louadurl(intenturl)
}eles{
  webview.louadurl(defualturl)
}`

Comment: i need the code i dont know haw to us it

Comment: yes i know haw to lead url . but i need to tell webview lead the intent url not the default url if receive  url from intent

Comment: Yes. All is about what you call intent url. And obtaining the intent url has nothing to do with your webview. Reword your problem please and change the subject of your post as you very well know how to open an url in a webview. Formulate your problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to everyone I have found a solution to the problem

firs you mut to add this code to manifest:

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
   <data android:mimeType="
</intent-filter>
```

Next add this code to MainActivity:

```
when (intent?.action) {
        Intent.ACTION_SEND -> {
            if ("text/plain" == intent.type) {
                webframe.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT))
            }
        }
        else -> {
            webframe.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get params in your activity by following code snippet:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri uri = intent.getData();
//uri is what you need.
```

Comment: Thnk you . now i have the url from intent.
so i need the code to make webview load url if intent sent from share menu eles load default url

Comment: ok,could you post your activity code and it's layout file in here?

Comment: If you don't know how to get action then here is `String action = intent.getAction()`and you can use `if(Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)){ //to something}else{//do smt}`.

Comment: Do you have any exist code in your project about opening url.

Comment: Your question makes others confused ,could you make it clear or more detailed?

Comment: i have webview and its load html file from device storage after open the app
`webframe.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")`;
i need to make my app open the uri after loead it from youtube not the default

Comment: Before invoking `webframe.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")`you can judage `action(which is come form intent.getAction())`,if action is `Intent.ACTION_SEND` then you load the `url`(come from intent.getData())

Comment: this is last
`val intent = intent
        intent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        val uri = intent.data

        if (uri == null){
            webframe.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")
        }else{
            webframe.loadUrl(uri.toString())
        }`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />              
<data android:host="www.youtube.com" android:mimeType="text/*" />
</intent-filter>
```